# Node js, signing a utf 8 line and sending it in a post request

Tags: php, node.js, axios, rsa, sha

There is this api https://spectrocoin.com/en/integration/spectrocoin.html that has perfectly working examples with Java and PHP .

I want to make a nodejs "createOrder" post request but I get an error message that says
  `[ { code: 99, message: 'Please check your request' } ]`

my code for creating the signature and sending a post request is as follows

```
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require("crypto");

function createOrder() {
  var privateKey = fs.readFileSync("./keys/private.pem");
  const dataToSign =
    "merchantId=" +
    merchantId +
    "&apiId=" +
    apiId +
    "&orderId=&payCurrency=BTC&payAmount=0.0&receiveCurrency=USD&receiveAmount=9.99&description=Order+%27Order001%27+at+www.merchant.com&culture=en&callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmerchant.com%2Fcallback.php&successUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmerchant.com%2Fsuccess.php&failureUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmerchant.com%2Ffailure.php";
  const signature = crypto.sign("sha1", Buffer.from(dataToSign), {
    key: privateKey,
    padding: crypto.constants.OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1,
  });

  console.log(signature.toString("base64"));

  var order = dataToSign + "&sign=" + signature;

  axios
    .post(
      "https://spectrocoin.com/api/merchant/1/createOrder",
      encodeURI(order),
      {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Connection: "Keep-Alive",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
      },
    )
    .then((r) => {
      console.log(r.data);
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}

createOrder();
```

The signature that I generate with this JS code is the same signature that I generate if I use the PHP library. And as mentioned the PHP example works perfectly.
What am I missing ?

Comment: If the signature is the same and valid in the PHP version, then it's probably up to how you send the request vs. the PHP version.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation of what do you mean ? Are you referring to the axios itself? or that I may need some more headers ? Or what ?